# Query Parameter, REST Post and then redirection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, redirect, jwt

I know little to zero about front end technologies. What I am trying to do is to implement Google Authorization. I will be creating a clickable link on my html page which will take the user to Google authorization. Once successful, Google will return to my page with `code` query parameter.

Here is where i am stuck. What i want to do is

1. Get `code` from query parameter
2. Send that `code` to my `REST` api end point
3. Once i receive `200` response with a JWT token, redirect to a new page with that `token` in query parameter so that token can further be used in subsequent calls.

I tried to use `AngularJS` but i couldn't figure out how to extract query parameter. I found couple of similar questions but they were talking about `ngRouter` etc and I don't have that much angular proficiency.

How can i setup this flow

Comment: There are whole modules available for this

Comment: Thats helpful. How would i search for those modules, example to use them. Specially for someone who has never written an AngularJS code.

Comment: Really need an explanation of how to use google search?